# Paypal IPN - custom Is Empty when Returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-ipn

Thank you ahead of time for any help you are able to give me.

I'm making a website in ASP.NET C# MVC 4 on which users will pay for a sort of in-game currency to be added to their account, and I'm using Paypal as sort of the bridge for my users to purchase this currency.  I've added a Buy Now button to my website that I've created using PayPal's sandbox test environment.  Here is the form's HTML code:

```
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="PayPal">
            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="@SessionManager.CurrentUser.UserID">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="MHV7ZLEXJC6YJ">
            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="CurrencyAmounts">
            <label for="os0">How Much?</label>
            <select name="os0">
                <option value="One Thousand">One Month $3.00 USD</option>
                <option value="Six Thousand">Six Months $15.00 USD</option>
                <option value="Ten Thousand">One Year $25.00 USD</option>
            </select>
            <br class="clearfix" />
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
```

Now, the form does send, I am able to login to my sandbox user to purchase it, and the transaction confirms.  My IPN listener is logging all the data that I get from IPN, however, and everytime, custom has no value.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you inspect the page (using dev tools) before submitting, do you see any value in the item_number form element?  That will tell you if it's just not getting filled in from the Session, or if it's getting lost after the POST.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a hosted button so the item number and other details would have to be setup when you create the button.  If you want to build the details into your HTML code like this you'll need to disable the "save button at PayPal" option in the button creation wizard, but of course that leaves your code vulnerable to people messing with it so you'll want to make sure you're checking that prices and everything match up when you get orders.

Comment: I tried doing that now that I'm using custom rather than item_number, and it didn't help...

Comment: Let me get a copy of the button code you're using now and I'll see if I can reproduce your problem.  I use custom with IPN all the time so I know it works in both the sandbox and production servers.